# R: Pattern in pearson residual, transform categorical varaible?

Tags: r, transformation

I need to plot a model with binomal GLM, I've only got a single categorical independent value (categorical treatment). The pearson residuals show a pattern which means I do not meet the model assumptions. I've tested for cooks distances of observations: none have a cooks distance of greater than 1.

[image]

I can't transform the independent (categorical value) so I don't know how I tackle this problem.

EDIT: my dataset: 
    `structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L), .Label = c("control", "9-tricosene", "tricosane", "7-tricosene", 
    "5-tricosene", "2-methyloctacosane", "heneicosane"), class = "factor"), 
    mating = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), courtship_count = c(0L, 2L, 13L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 16L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("treatment", "mating", "courtship_count"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -168L), class = "data.frame")`

So there are 7 treatment levels including the control. 
My current model is this one: 
`fitmating=glm(mating~treatment, family=binomial(link=logit), data=datafig4)`

Comment: This seems to be a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I have voted to migrate.

Comment: And also, provide a sample of the data `dput(yourData)` and the code and coefficients of your general linear model. It might also be good to know how many levels there are in your predictor variable.